# Filter out records that exceed certain count

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

was hoping someone could advise on the following problem.

I have a table similar to below and am trying to filter out all IDs that have the same subject and date (not just dedupe but remove complete) from my output.

| ID | Date | Subject | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 1/22/22 | Welcome> | Email |
| def | 1/23/22 | Offer! | Call |
| xyz | 1/22/22 | Welcome> | Email |

So in the example above we would want to remove both rows with subject, "Welcome>"

I am able to write a query that shows me the count of IDs per subject and date, but stuck finding a way to remove these from my final output.

```
  select distinct 
  activitydate,
  name,
  subject,
  count (id)
  from activity
  where activity.activitydate between X and Y'
  and type IN ('Email')
  group by 1,2,3
  having count (id) > 30
  order by count (id) desc
```

Please let me know if any further details are needed and thank you in advance!

Comment: So a few things (bare in mind I'm not familiar with snowflake), 1 - this is probably a typo here there is an extra single quote after the between, 2 - your query looks correct, some RDBMs don't like the space between the function and the parenthesis `count (id) -> count(id)`, if the `having count` is not working try adding an alias to the count column and wrap the whole query as a subquery and filter it on the outer query.

Comment: Again one of above points may be your problem or something else related to the variables you are not providing. Doc's says it is correct: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/having.html

Comment: If may even be the `activity.activitydate` as your table above your query doesn't have such field it is just `Date`

Comment: Hi George, the table I wrote as an example above so the `Date` is indeed `activity.activitydate`. In my source query I actually hard coded in a date range and did not use variables, just used them above as an example.

Comment: To simplify: * all ids are unique * we are trying to remove all ids that have the same subject and date above a given count

Answer (score 1):

```
-- Filter out all IDs that have the same subject and date
SELECT
    Date,
    Subject,
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    activity
GROUP BY 
    Date,
    Subject
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) < 2
```

Comment: Hi Austin, the above will not work because there are no duplicate ids here. We are trying to remove those that have the same subject and date above a certain count, but the ids themselves are unique.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the rows where the COUNT by ID and SUBJECT is > 1 then you can do some thing like this.

-- untested

```
SELECT * FROM activity 
WHERE (ID,SUBJECT) NOT IN 
(SELECT ID,SUBJECT FROM activity 
GROUP BY ID, SUBJECT HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

Comment: So the tricky part of this problem is that each record id is unique. 

If you notice my example above, we are trying to remove all record ids that have the same subject and date within a given count.

So if we have 30 records with subject, “hello” and date “2022-01-01” we want to remove all those records/rows from my final output from the activity table.

Comment: Try this and let us know if it works  
 
 SELECT * FROM  activity WHERE ID NOT IN (
 SELECT ID from activity WHERE SUBJECT IN (
    SELECT COUNT(*) , SUBJECT FROM activity GROUP BY  SUBJECT HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
  )
   )

Comment: Hi @Himanshu Kandpal the above did not work because there are no duplicate ids in this table. As mentioned, we are trying to remove all ids that have the same subject and date but each id is unique itself.